# Global MediaElement will not restart once stopped, wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-8

I have an app that runs background music at the application level so that the music doesn't stop when the user navigates through pages. However, I also make use of a VideoBrush. As I found out, I cannot have the two running at the same time as the VideoBrush will crash when setting its source.

I found that if I set the source of the MediaElement to null when the user attempts to use the VideoBrush, that everything works. Sure the music stops, much to my chagrin, but no error happens.

However, when the user taps away from the VideoBrush, I am trying to make the music start back up (beginning is fine) to no avail. Simply put, I am having trouble getting the music to start up again.

Here is my code:

**App.xaml**

```
    <Application.Resources>

        <MediaElement x:Key="GlobalMedia" Source="minutelongsong.mp3"
         MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" Visibility="Collapsed" />

    </Application.Resources>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    public static MediaElement GlobalMediaElement
    {
        get { return Current.Resources["GlobalMedia"] as MediaElement; }
    }

    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        var AppMediaElement = App.GlobalMediaElement;
        AppMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        AppMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var AppMediaElement = App.GlobalMediaElement;
        AppMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
        AppMediaElement.Play();
    }
```

And now the page that is making use of the VideoBrush.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas" Width="480" Height="800" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush" Stretch="Fill">
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="previewTransform"
                        CenterX=".5"
                        CenterY=".5" />
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    private void Button_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        var AppMediaElement = App.GlobalMediaElement;
        AppMediaElement.Pause();
        AppMediaElement.Stop();
        AppMediaElement.Source = null; //set it to null to allow the cam to be set.


        if ((PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary)))
        {
           viewfinderCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
           cam = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
           if (Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp || Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitDown || Orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait)
           {

               videoBrush.RelativeTransform = new CompositeTransform() { CenterX = 0.5, CenterY = 0.5, Rotation = 90 };
           }

           videoBrush.SetSource(cam);
        }
```

When the user exits out of the camera VideoBrush by hitting an on screen button, this code is fired. It disposes the cam, and tries to get the music playing again if the user allows the music. **However the music will not play, even with this code.**

```
    private void zoomout_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cam != null)
        {
            cam.Dispose();
        }

        viewfinderCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        if (allowingamemusic == true)
        {
            var AppMediaElement = App.Current.Resources["GlobalMedia"] as MediaElement;
            AppMediaElement.Source = new Uri("minutelongsong.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            AppMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
            AppMediaElement.Play(); //despite this here, it will not play. No error thrown.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I switch back and forth between capturing an image and audio in the same page on my phone app.

You were very close, but you also have to set the videoBrush source to something else or it won't let go of the resources.

So when you want to use the MediaElement, then first dispose of the camera like this:

```
cam.Dispose();
viewfinderBrush.SetSource(new MediaElement()); //so it will let go of cam
cam = null;
//now set source for MediaElemet and do whatever
```

And when you use the camera again:

```
mediaElement.Stop();
mediaElement.Source = null; //or else setting the source for the video brush will fail
//now set source for videoBrush and do whatever
```

Old question, but hopefully this will help someone... it took me a few tries to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After writing this last night, and finally testing it this morning, I see what may have happened but am still having the problem of the music not replaying once it's stopped.

MediaElement.MediaFailed was for the entire time being called. I found out that it was calling: AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR. This error is thrown when Zune is running and my device is USB connected to the same computer.

It was suggested that I deploy my app to my phone, close zune, and disconnect the USB. I tried this, and the music still did not play once I tried to replay it. This also happened on the emulator too.

The same AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR is still being thrown.

Since then, I have given up on this as I spent a few hours not finding out how to make this happen. So, I have since gone with the MediaPlayer class and will be using that instead.

------ If anyone solves this problem, I will give you the checkmark for a correct answer.